# Encrypting and decrypting when the data is not a multiple of the key size

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography

I have a tricky issue which I am not able to resolve. I am creating a dll which accepts an unsigned character buffer and its size (as it is binary). Then I would encrypt it and return the buffer. The caller of this function will later write this buffer to a file.

As the file size would be large, the caller will be sending me buffer to encrypt in chunks (its not fixed size) before writing to file. Eventually the final file is encrypted.

Now for encryption, I am using a 16-character key which encrypts each character of the buffer. Since the buffer size will not be in multiples of 16, there are cases that all the characters of my key may not be used in encryption. This creates a problem during decryption. Because not all characters are encrypted using the same key pattern. So, decryption fails.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

All [block ciphers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher) with symmetric keys like [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) require the input to be a multiple of the block size.  They solve this problem by [padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)) data such that it is always a multiple of the block size.  The size of a "block" in this case is simply the size of the key.

A common approach to padding is [PKCS#7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2315), where the character you choose for padding represents the number of bytes you are padding.  E.g., let's say your block size is 16 bytes and your data is 60 bytes long.  That means you can fill up 3 blocks completely.  Your last block will have 12 bytes of data, and 4 unused bytes.  So you you fill all 4 unused bytes with the value 4.  If you had 61 bytes of data, you'd have 3 unused bytes in your last block, and so you'd pad it with 3 bytes of the value 3.

You should design your API so that your library adds the padding when encrypting and removes the padding when decrypting.  The user should not have to do it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sounds like a perfect solution for my problem. Will there be any situation where my padded value will be same as actual value? How can we distinguish in such a scenario?

Comment: PKCS#7 padding is unambiguous, meaning you can always tell what is padding by looking at the last byte and then subtracting that number of bytes from the data buffer.  The implication is that if your input is exactly the length of the block size, you *must* add an extra block of just padding (all with the value 16) even though without PKCS#7 you wouldn't need to pad in that situation.  Alternatively for other padding schemes, you could encrypt a small header on your data telling you the length.

Comment: I'd like to note also that nothing about this scheme protects your data from tampering.  If you add a length header, there's nothing stopping an attacker from simply flipping a bit in the encrypted data and then when you decrypt it you end up with a different length.  I have answered this question under the assumption that your encryption scheme is for educational purposes only.

Answer (score 2):

The way you've described this problem suggests you're using the ECB mode of your cipher. ECB (Electronic Codebook) means that you encrypt each block independently. This is an incredibly insecure way to encrypt, so insecure that in many cases it barely qualifies as encryption.

If you encrypt each 16 bytes independently, then any time the same 16 bytes appears in the plaintext, the same 16 bytes will appear in the ciphertext. In data with any patterns in it (and most data has patterns in it), this can be used to decrypt the data.

To solve this, we almost always use another block cipher mode, such as CBC (which is the most common). CBC mixes the output of each block into the encryption of the next block. When using CBC, it is common to use PKCS#7 padding as @indiv describes. There are other solutions, but PKCS#7 is common and easy to implement. Note that when using it, if the data you are given is a multiple of 16 bytes, then you need to add an extra block of 16 0x10 bytes.

You should not pad with zeros. This is ambiguous (what if the original data ended in zeros?) and allows for extension attacks. That is why PKCS#7 exists.

Writing your own crypto is very challenging and it is very easy to get things wrong. I recommend using an established library, which will have the tools you need to handle these situations. In C++, you should look at [cryptopp](http://www.cryptopp.com) or [Botan](http://botan.randombit.net). If you use Botan, you may want to consider using their CryptoBox format. It handles the more complicated issues for you (and there are a lot of complicated issues in building a crypto format).

Comment: thank you adding more insight to it. Based on the solutions proposed here, I see that user should be forced to send data in multiples of 16 as my dll just processes the buffer and don't do any file operation. So, I would also need to let user to add dummy data for padding. I am not sure if they are ok with that. Talking about Crypto or Botan, does it still expect the input to be in multiples of key size? I will read through the Crypto & Botan to understand more.

Comment: The CryptoBox format doesn't actually require a 16-byte data multiple because it uses CTR mode rather than CBC. There are many block cipher modes with various trade-offs. You should not expect your caller to add dummy data. You should handle all padding internally (and that's what the PKCS#7 scheme is for). Again, building a crypto format is very tricky. You may also consider the RNCryptor format, which I maintain. There is a C++ implementation (that I do not maintain) at https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-cpp.

Comment: The key here is that there are encryption algorithms like AES, and there are encryption modes like CBC (giving AES-CBC), and then there are encryption *formats* like RNCryptor, CryptoBox, OpenSSL, and AESCrypt. Since each layer can introduce its own problems, you are encouraged to pick from the highest level you can (so it is better to use a high-level format like CryptoBox rather than building your own AES-CBC encryptor).

Comment: I will check RNCryptor and Cryptobox. Like indiv suggested, I will not add a header to store the size rather try to use standard libraries. Thank you both for providing these valuable suggestions